# How to column family count using pycassa

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

Does anyone know how to get column family count using pycassa?
I was able to get the key space count. but don't see an option to get the column family count.

```
system = SystemManager(server, auth)
keyspaces = system.list_keyspaces()
print len(keyspaces)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `get_keyspace_column_families(keyspace, use_dict_for_col_metadata=False)`**

> Returns a raw description of the keyspace
>
> If use_dict_for_col_metadata is True, the CfDef’s column_metadata will be stored as a dictionary where the keys are column names instead of a list.
>
> Returns a dictionary of the form {column_family_name: CfDef}

Example to show number of column families in keyspace : `my_keyspace`

```
print len(system.get_keyspace_column_families('my_keyspace'))
```

Comment: It works for the tables with cli syntax., but I don't think it works for the Tables with CQL syntax.

    system.get_keyspace_column_families('my_keyspace'))

this always gives only the first CF/Table but not all the tables.

Comment: This should give you all the Table of my_keyspace. I have tested it